# Check if a substring of a string is in a list of strings in python

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, nlp

I have a dictionary of foods:

```
foods={
  "chicken masala" : "curry",
  "chicken burger" : "burger",
  "beef burger" : "burger",
  "chicken soup" : "appetizer",
  "vegetable" : "curry"
}
```

Now I have a list of strings:

```
queries = ["best burger", "something else"]
```

I have to find out if there is any string in `queries` that has and entry in our `food` dictionary. 
Like in the above example it should return True for `best burger`. 
Currently, I am calculating cosine similarity between each string in the list for all the entries in the `foods.keys()`. 
It works but it's very time inefficient. The `food` dictionary has almost 1000 entries. Is there any efficient way to do so?

**Edit:**

Here the best burger should be returned because there is `burger` in it and `burger` is also present in `chicken burger` in `foods.keys()`. I am basically trying to find out if there is any query which is a food type.

This is how I am calculating :

```
import re, math
from collections import Counter

WORD = re.compile(r'\w+')

def get_cosine(text1, text2):
     vec1 = text_to_vector(text1.lower())
     vec2 = text_to_vector(text2.lower())
     intersection = set(vec1.keys()) & set(vec2.keys())
     numerator = sum([vec1[x] * vec2[x] for x in intersection])

     sum1 = sum([vec1[x]**2 for x in vec1.keys()])
     sum2 = sum([vec2[x]**2 for x in vec2.keys()])
     denominator = math.sqrt(sum1) * math.sqrt(sum2)

     if not denominator:
        return 0.0
     else:
        return (float(numerator) / denominator) * 100

foods={
  "chicken masala" : "curry",
  "chicken burger" : "burger",
  "beef burger" : "burger",
  "chicken soup" : "appetizer",
  "vegetable" : "curry"
}
queries = ["best burger", "something else"]
flag = False
food = []
for phrase in queries:
   for k in foods.keys():
      cosine = get_cosine(phrase, k)
      if int(cosine) > 40:
         flag = True
         food.append(phrase)
         break

print('Foods:', food)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Foods: ['best burger']
```

Solution:
Though @Black Thunder's solution works for the example I have provided in the example but it doesn't work for queries like `best burgers`. But this solution works in that case. Which is a major concern for me. Thanks @Andrej Kesely. This was the reason I went for the cosine similarity in my solution. But i think SequenceMatcher works better here.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: And its a bit unclear too

Comment: I am calculating cosine similarity  between each entry in queries and each entry in food.keys() @BlackThunder

Comment: 1000 entries is not much

Comment: why dont you show the code you have tried which works but is inefficent. that will make it much easier for people to suggest performance improvments.

Comment: @Anurag what about a test on set intersection after splitting on whitespace? This could work if you didn't mind about missing fuzzy matches on things like "burgers" and "burger".

Comment: @ongenz, it will be actually better if we can math even if someone queries for best burgers and we can find the entries containing burger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `difflib` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher)) to find similarities (It will probably need some tweaking with coefficients):

```
foods={
  "chicken masala" : "curry",
  "chicken burger" : "burger",
  "beef burger" : "burger",
  "chicken soup" : "appetizer",
  "vegetable" : "curry"
}

queries = ["best burger", "order"]

from difflib import SequenceMatcher

out = []
for q in queries:
    for k in foods:
        r = SequenceMatcher(None, k, q).ratio()
        print('q={: <20} k={: <20} ratio={}'.format(q, k, r))
        if r > 0.5:
            out.append(k)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
q=best burger          k=chicken masala       ratio=0.16
q=best burger          k=chicken burger       ratio=0.64
q=best burger          k=beef burger          ratio=0.8181818181818182
q=best burger          k=chicken soup         ratio=0.2608695652173913
q=best burger          k=vegetable            ratio=0.3
q=order                k=chicken masala       ratio=0.10526315789473684
q=order                k=chicken burger       ratio=0.3157894736842105
q=order                k=beef burger          ratio=0.375
q=order                k=chicken soup         ratio=0.11764705882352941
q=order                k=vegetable            ratio=0.14285714285714285
['chicken burger', 'beef burger']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
queries = ["best burger", "order"]
foods={
  "chicken masala" : "curry",
  "chicken burger" : "burger",
  "beef burger" : "burger",
  "chicken soup" : "appetizer",
  "vegetable" : "curry"
}
output = []
for y in queries:                 #looping through the queries
    for x in y.split(" "):        #spliting the data in the queries for matches
        for z in foods:           #taking the keys (same as foods.keys)
            if x in z:            #Checking if the data in queries matches any data in the keys
                output.append(z)  #if matches, appending the data
print(output)
```

Output:

```
['chicken burger', 'beef burger']
```

Comment: Thank you @Black Thunder. I was just calculating the complexity. Your code will have O(n*m) complexity. But I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something simple like this

First get all the keys

```
data = foods.keys()
```

Now convert list of strings to one single string comma separated. This will be much easier to check for substring matching,

```
queries = ','.join(queries)
```

Now check for substring matching

```
for food in data:
    food = food.split()
        for item in food:
            if item in data:
                print True
```

Answer (score -1):

If what you want is a list of matches between queries and foods keys, you could use a list comprehension:

`matches = [food for food in queries if food in foods]`

Comment: The output list must not be empty

Comment: Oh my bad. We need a list of booleans then?